# SQL Change position

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one field like this

```
username
Vo, Tony (12322)
Beaty, Nancy (34343)
```

I want to change first name in front like this

```
username
Tony Vo (12322)
Nancy Beaty (34343)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: And what [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: MS sql  and dont know how to do it. I can separate them but not like this

Comment: Are you saying you want to convert "Foo, Bar" to "Bar Foo" in SQL?

Comment: you're right on

Comment: Names are weird. You have no idea the can of worms you're about to open. Also, it's poor practice to put two fields (name, plus a sequence number of some kind) in the same column.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @CoolTable AS TABLE (id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), [name] nvarchar(100))
INSERT INTO @CoolTable values
    ('Man, Jo (123546)'),
    ('Vo, Tony (5533)'),
    ('Beaty, Nancy (7766)'),
    (',badData1 (100)'),
    ('badData2 (101)'),
    (',badData3')

SELECT
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', [name]) > 0 AND CHARINDEX('(', [name]) > 0 THEN
        RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING([name], CHARINDEX(',', [name])+1, CHARINDEX('(', [name]) - CHARINDEX(',', [name]) - 1)))
        + ' '
        + SUBSTRING([name], 0, CHARINDEX(',', [name]))
        + ' '
        + LTRIM(SUBSTRING([name], CHARINDEX('(', [name]) - 1, 100))
    ELSE
        [name]
    END AS [NewName]
FROM @CoolTable
```

Output:

```
NewName
---------------------------
Jo Man (123546)
Tony Vo (5533)
Nancy Beaty (7766)
badData1  (100)
badData2 (101)
,badData3
```

This code does not bring joy to me. And per Marie Kondo, I should remove it. If it was up to me, I would see how to improve the process how the original data was inserted (e.g. get in 3 different fields).

Comment: The charindex function requires 2 to 3 arguments on my table. Please see my data above. i believe the number will create error. It will work without number

Comment: Check the documentation for your database. For MS SQL it is `CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind , expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )   `

Comment: Start_location is optional, but if it is saying it is required, you can use 0.

Comment: Updated to add the `(number)` in there. Sorry, I completely missed it in my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your sample data is representative and consistent with your actual data, you could try [**parsename**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
select trim(parsename(name,2) + 
            parsename(name,3) + ' (' + 
            parsename(name,1)) as new_name
from your_table t1
cross apply (select translate(username,',(','..') as name) t2;
```

You could also use a subquery or a `CTE` instead of a `cross apply`

```
with cte as 
(select translate(username,',(','..') as username 
 from your_table)

select trim(parsename (username,2) + 
            parsename (username,3) + ' (' +
            parsename (username,1))
from cte;
```

Comment: sorry, it does not work. the value return NULL and I have more than 100 records not just 3 records.

Comment: @user13636604 It works for the sample data you provided. If your sample data is not representative of your actual data, you might want to update your question
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=681d59fbc1013dcf96c83b81927f0ddb